# IBDesignable and multiple targets in Swift

Tags: ios, interface-builder, swift2, xcode7, ibdesignable

Seems like **IBDesignable** has some problems with multiple targets and **swift** modules. After I've added new target (my app has 2 targets now, e.g. *seller* and *buyer*), my *StoryBoard* began to halt views building with warning:

```
Storyboard: warning: IB Designables: Using class UITextField for object with  
custom class because the class _TtC15******Buyer11HCTextField does not exist
```

I think, designables compiler fails to find proper *swift** module somehow.
Any suggestions how to fix this?

Pic:

[image]

I'm using **Xcode 7.0.1** and **Swift2**

Comment: I'm also noticing this issue, although there is one thing you should check. Double check that your IBDesignable files are added to both the 'buyer' and 'seller' targets.

Comment: @MikeCole, no luck! The solution: move custom views to separate framework.

Comment: I was afraid of that. We have that approach working, but it seems like such overhead.

Comment: @MikeCole, kind of. Forces to link lots of frameworks and pods with this Designables framework. But the build time decreased dramatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution is... Create a framework!
It solves all the problem. Just keep your designables in separate bundle.

Comment: Having the same issue, I also have multiple targets and currently trying to use a custom UIView from github. I drag the file to my project so that I can customize. I guess I should use Cocoapods